# Interpretation of potential difference of a capacitor

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, electric-circuits, electric-fields

Suppose I have 2 charges of arbitrary charge separated by a distance of 2a. The potential at a point, say A, finite distance from the two charges is the sum of the potentials at that point because of the individual charges. Now, if there is another point B, we know its potential can be calculated in the same way as A. Potential difference between the two points, therefore, is the collective effect of both the charges.

Now my question is, is this the same interpretation of the potential difference between the 2 conductors of a capacitor?

Please do correct me if my interpretation is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the interpretation is exactly the same.